# Show div from a not shown div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Is it possible to show a div from a not shown div without the rest reappearing?

So that after including the page I filter the div called main-content and show the sub-content.

I have built an AJAX- include system for a Page whit both a mobile and a pc version. But the mobile version doesn’t have to show everything
Something like this:

the included HTML:

```
<div id="main-content">
Bla bla
<div id=“sub-content“>
Hi hi
</div>
Bla Bla
</div>
```

In the mobile version:

```
<div id=“sub-content“>
Hi hi
</div>
```

But in the pc version

```
 <div id="main-content">
Bla bla
<div id=“sub-content“>
Hi hi
</div>
Bla Bla
</div>
```

Ps. Sorry for my english

Comment: You cannot. But why `sub-content` is a child? You can create it as sibling of `main-content` and show it if mobile is accessing the website or if you want to show the PC users a short content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've got this correct, no - not without restructuring your HTML or adding javascript - as the parent DIV is not shown then that will automatically hide any child content no matter what you try. I'm afraid that's the way CSS works I'm afraid. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your content which you want to hide in another div and give those div a another class.

So now dont hide your `<div id="main-content">` hide your newly created divs inside main-content!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem this is a possible solution:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   //args,
   success: function(result) {
      if (checkMobile()) {
          jQuery(result).find('#sub-conten').appendTo( jQuery('#container') );
      else
          jQuery(result).appendTo( jQuery('#container') );
   }
});
```

The function checkMobile(), after checking the device returns true or false.

It is not possible to show a div inside a hidden div.